# Problem installing a package

Tags: tar

I am a new user, trying to install a downloaded tar.bz2 package. I have extracted the files into a folder on my desktop. I am trying to follow the directions here: [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

But they say "Make sure you read a file called INSTALL, INSTALL.txt, README, or something similar if one was extracted." But I don't see a file with that name. What should I do?

Comment: Don't you have a README file? What are the contents of the package? Isn't there a installation instruction at the source from where you got the package?

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a link to the tarball (.tar.bz2) archive you downloaded, or where you got it, so we can see what is inside and what the README is actually called.

Comment: Hi, what software do you want to install and on which OS (Ubuntu, ...)? Have you tried to compile the software (after changing into the extracted directory) as described above? Are you sure, the package contains a C / C++ source code?

Comment: The package is monero-gui-linux-x64-v0.12.0.0. It has a file titled "start-gui.sh" which I opened.  I don't know if it's the right one tho. The contents of that file say:

Comment: #!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/libs
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=`pwd`/plugins
export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=`pwd`/qml
# make it so that it can be called from anywhere and also through soft links
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(test -L "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" && readlink "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" || echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")")"
"$SCRIPT_DIR"/monero-wallet-gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have downloaded Monero GUI Linux 64-bit 0.12.0.0 Lithium Luna, from [official link](https://dlsrc.getmonero.org/gui/monero-gui-linux-x64-v0.12.0.0.tar.bz2) I hope.

So you have *monero-gui-linux-x64-v0.12.0.0.tar.bz2* file in your *~/Downloads* folder. Then you can extract it by any known way.
The folder *monero-gui-v0.12.0.0* will be created here.

This directory has *start-gui.sh*, you can click on it or run it from terminal with `./start-gui.sh`.

Comment: Thanks - that worked. Clicking on the file did not start it up but the command line worked.

Comment: Then you can [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) my answer :)